# Create all lags of given columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm creating a `pandas.DataFrame` out of lags from an existing `pandas.DataFrame`, using `DataFrame.shift` and `pandas.concat`. There are a two aspects I don't like about this code:

1. Using `np.ones_like` to create constants
2. Building up a list of lag tables and using `pandas.concat` to combine them

```
"""
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'GDP': [100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150],
...                    'INV': [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50]})

>>> lagged_dataframe(df, lags=3)
   GDP  INV  GDP_Int  INV_Int  GDP_Lag01  INV_Lag01  GDP_Lag02  INV_Lag02  \\
0  100    0        1        1        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
1  110   10        1        1      100.0        0.0        NaN        NaN
2  120   20        1        1      110.0       10.0      100.0        0.0
3  130   30        1        1      120.0       20.0      110.0       10.0
4  140   40        1        1      130.0       30.0      120.0       20.0
5  150   50        1        1      140.0       40.0      130.0       30.0
<BLANKLINE>
   GDP_Lag03  INV_Lag03
0        NaN        NaN
1        NaN        NaN
2        NaN        NaN
3      100.0        0.0
4      110.0       10.0
5      120.0       20.0

"""

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def constants(df):
    new_columns = ["{}_Int".format(variable) for variable in df.columns]
    return pd.DataFrame(np.ones_like(df.loc[:,:]), index=df.index, columns=new_columns)

def lag(df, n):
    new_columns = ["{}_Lag{:02d}".format(variable, n) for variable in df.columns]
    new_df = df.shift(n)
    new_df.columns = new_columns
    return new_df

def lagged_dataframe(df, lags=1):
    data_frames = [df]
    data_frames.append(constants(df))
    data_frames.extend([lag(df, i) for i in range(1, lags + 1)])
    return pd.concat(data_frames, axis=1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod(verbose=True, optionflags=doctest.NORMALIZE_WHITESPACE)
```

Comment: Can you edit the post to explain what this code is supposed to do, please? It is hard to review code unless we know what problem it is supposed to solve.

Answer (score 2):

Well you've written you don't like it, but why?  Is this ever used with relevantly large input?  If so, you might have to consider allocating the right size of data frame from the start and assign the values afterwards.

If not, I can only see some small things that could be a little bit more succinct, and perhaps `np.ones_like(df)` instead of with `df.loc[:,:]` ... but otherwise this seems fine?

Like the following removes a bit of duplicated code, but is not inherently better:

```
def suffixed_columns(df, suffix):
    return ["{}{}".format(column, suffix) for column in df.columns]

def constants(df):
    return pd.DataFrame(np.ones_like(df), index=df.index, columns=suffixed_columns(df, "_Int"))

def lag(df, n):
    new_df = df.shift(n)
    new_df.columns = suffixed_columns(df, "_Lag{:02d}".format(n))
    return new_df

def lagged_dataframe(df, lags=1):
    return pd.concat([df, constants(df)] + [lag(df, i) for i in range(1, lags + 1)], axis=1)
```